# what are all available setRequestProperty's for URLConnection

Tags: java, android, http

I am developing an Android app to investigate the use of URLConnection and obtaining data in JSON format.

i have found many good resources and examples of how to code this

where do i find a complete list of all the valid RequestProperty's?
such as shown here?

```
urlconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
urlconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(params.getBytes().length));
urlconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
```

what have i missed?

as a suplementary question (if i may)
does URLConnection have a mechanism to "force" retires of POST's and GET's?
if it does, how do you set this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second question first. You may want to set a`timeout` on the connection as :

```
  urlconn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
  urlconn.setReadTimeout(10000);
```

Coming back to question 1, technically you can set any property you want. **If the property is not already there in the properties list, its simply adds the new property with the specified value in the list.**

If you are referring `http` connection, you may set any property which is supported by the `html` header depending on the `usage/need` of the property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and time), I imagine then that this approach requires me to code a retry loop when either timeout condition is raised?

Comment: It depends on the timeout condition and your requirement. Please note: I updated the answer of your first question as well.